# Can someone provide a derivation of the integral result of $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\sinh^{-1}(x)+c$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have found other variations of the above integral such as:

$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\int{\sec{\theta}d{\theta}}=\log{|\sec{\theta}+\tan{\theta}|}+c$ ,using appropriate substitution

Kindly let know what substitution can be made to get the result in title.

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry, corrected now

Comment: Ok. Now, *the substitution you asked for* is simply:$$x=\sinh\theta,\,dx=\cosh\theta d\theta,\,\sqrt{1+x^2}=\cosh\theta.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$y=\sinh^{-1}x$$
$$\implies x=\sinh(y)$$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{dy}=\cosh(y)$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{ \cosh(y)}$$
But we also know that $$\cosh(y)=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(y)}=\sqrt{1+x^2}$$
So $$\frac{d}{dx}\sinh^{-1}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
So integrating both sides we get $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\sinh^{-1}(x)+c
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have two answers by two substitutions:

Putting $x=\tan \theta$ gives $$
\begin{aligned}
I =\ln |\sec \theta+\tan \theta|+C_1=\ln \left(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\right)+C_1
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting $x=\sinh \theta$ gives

$$I=\operatorname{arcsinh} x+C_2$$
Actually, we can prove that the answers by letting
$$y= \ln \left(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\right) $$

By the definition of logarithm, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
& e^y=\sqrt{1+x^2}+x \textrm{ and } \\
& e^{-y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-x}= \sqrt{1+x^2}-x
\end{aligned}
$$
Adding them together yields
$$
\sinh y=\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2}=x \Rightarrow \ln \left(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\right) =y=\operatorname{arcsinh} x
$$